# .net cache lib with auto async cache refresh

Tags: c#, .net, caching

**Context**

I have en application which have some heavy calculations and data queries.

To avoid having every user wait for the same results i use men cache

**The problem**

This is fine and all, but when the cache timeout occurs, the unlucky user pays the penalty of refreshing the. Ie waiting for result before carrying on

**the Question**

I would like there to be an additional timeout that says. I'll give you the cache value, but I will start refreshing the cache in another thread.

You could say: *automatic async cache refresh*

How would one solve this? It sounds difficult to get right.

*original question too tooling specific, kept for completeness*

> I have been looking for a Long time after an.net equivalent caching
>   library to caffeine in the java world.
>
> I've found lacycache, which is fine
>
> *But the number one missing feature is:*
>
> **auto async cache refresh**
>
> The point is to minimize the amount of times a user waits on cache
>   refresh.
>
> Is there any lib solving that?

Comment: What do you mean by auto async cache refresh?  Regardless, asking for tooling suggestions is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: What kind of app are you building? Web or something else?

Comment: The app kind should be unimportant. I'm looking for some standalone code, not something part of a bigger framework

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/dpatekar/CacheAnt
It refreshes your cache in the background at specified intervals and you always retrieve the last stored version.